# server time zone value 'CDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When trying to connect to a mySQL on my website I get this message
    `java.sql.SQLException`:

> The server time zone value 'CDT' is unrecognized or 
>       represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or 
>       JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more 
>       specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

I did try using

```
serverTimezone=CDT
```

but I get this
    `java.sql.SQLException`:

> No timezone mapping entry for 'CDT'

Comment: You may have to do some work to configure your MySQL timezone tables, [see here](https://datawookie.netlify.com/blog/2017/08/setting-up-time-zones-in-mysql/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CDT is not a valid timezone identifier. It's an abbreviation for a number of different timezones e.g. Central Daylight Time or Cuba Daylight Time.

Most likely you want to configure `America/Chicago` timezone if you are looking for American central time. You can check what values are available in your MySQL server by running `select * from time_zone_name;` query.

Comment: This is how it goes. I can add that if the default time zone in mysql version 8.0.20 was not set then java connector chooses(gets?) default parameter "system_time_zone" which is FLE Summer Time" here in Helsinki. In this case adding default-time-zone='Europe/Helsinki' to my.ini (in windows) repaired Java's mysql connection.