# The server time zone value 'KST' is unrecognized: How to fix server-side?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, jdbc, timezone

I am running a MySQL client utility, and getting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52906554/server-time-zone-value-cdt-is-unrecognized-or-represents-more-than-one-time-zo) [well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719818/the-server-time-zone-value-aest-is-unrecognized-or-represents-more-than-one-ti)-[known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57052070/time-zone-issue-with-database) error:

> The server time zone value 'KST' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

Out-of-the-box Ubuntu 2019.04 with the database engine installed from the official Ubuntu repository (mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26).

How to fix it?

Appending `&serverTimezone=UTC` to the JDBC URL would fix the problem **but unfortunately I can not control the URL used by the utility** so I have to work around the problem server-side.

I tried running `SET time_zone = "+09:00";` on the MySQL server, it does not fix the problem.

This *might* be part of the problem:

```
select * from mysql.time_zone_name;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

`env | grep KST` returns nothing.

Comment: Did you try the other answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by `KST` you mean Korea Standard Time as used in South Korea, use the [TZDB identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) `Asia/Seoul`.

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Asia/Seoul';
```

`KST` isn't a valid TZDB identifier.